# Tarantool app memory limit

Tags: lua, tarantool

good day
i'm a newibe to tarantool and i hava question about memory limit for client application inside tarantool
i have in-memory database for 300 millions items and lua application that select part of them, after select i wrap result to '*class*' for simpler interaction from code. For example:

```
Foo = {}
Foo.__index = Foo

function Foo.create(rawData)
    local self = setmetatable({}, Foo)

    self.PrimaryId = rawData[1]
    self.BarId     = rawData[2]

    local fields = rawData[3]
    self.Name    = fields[1]
    self.Date    = fields[2]

    return self
end
```

and usage:

```
local data = box.space.Foo.index.barId:select({barId})
local ctor = Foo.create
local foo = {}

for i = 1, #data do
    table.insert(foo, ctor(data[i]))
end
```

on first run in most cases it run successful, but on second it with 100% probability fails with message (tarantool message):

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (not enough memory)
```

i'm understand, that there is problems with memory usage (non released memory), but i have question about limit - is there some limit to lua application? because i see in monitor for memory consumption and note that there are enough free memory and fail appeared after application start using more then 1.2 Gb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tarantool uses luajit, that means that the limitation came from luajit [1].

Also, luajit (like lua) has an issue with a garbage collector[2], sometimes you have to call it manually[3] or you will have "OOM panic".

[1] Links:

- https://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/LuaJIT-x64-limited-to-31-bit-address-space-even-without-MAP-32BIT-restrictions
- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-11/msg00241.html
- http://timetobleed.com/digging-out-the-craziest-bug-you-never-heard-about-from-2008-a-linux-threading-regression/

[2] http://wiki.luajit.org/New-Garbage-Collector

[3] http://luatut.com/collectgarbage.html